# Remove space in column names from DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, foreach, datatable

I have a `DataTable` which I populate from an excel sheet. The column names in the excel contain space between the two words i.e.

1. PRODUCT TYPE
2. SERIAL NUMBER

And I'm trying to achieve

1. PRODUCTTYPE or PRODUCT_TYPE
2. SERIALNUMBER or SERIAL_NUMBER

The `DataTable` columns are dynamically generated from the excel. I'm trying to remove the space between the words but I can't seem to get it to work. My current code for removing the white spaces looks like

```
foreach (DataRow dr in cloned.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in cloned.Columns)
    {
        dr[col] = dr[col].ToString().Replace(" ", "");
    }
}
```

can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Comment: try with .Replace(" ", String.Empty)

Comment: What he said. ^

Comment: @Manu still the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to loop the rows if you want to modify the columns:

```
foreach(DataColumn c in cloned.Columns)
    c.ColumnName = String.Join("_", c.ColumnName.Split());
```

Use `String.Join("", c.ColumnName.Split())` if you want to remove the spaces.

Answer (score 3):

First you don't need to loop the rows of the `DataTable`

```
foreach (DataColumn col in cloned.Columns)
{
    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ","");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below methods too in your foreach loop.

```
public static string TrimAllWithSplitAndJoin(string str)
{
    return string.Concat(str.Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}


static Regex whitespace = new Regex(@"\s+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static string TrimAllWithRegex(string str)
{
    return whitespace.Replace(str, "");
}


foreach (DataColumn col in cloned.Columns)
{
    col.ColumnName = TrimAllWithSplitAndJoin(col.ColumnName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better to put checking process of the data column, when the column type is string then remove the space

```
 if (col.DataType == typeof(System.String))
  {
  dr[col] = dr[col].ToString().Replace(" ", "");
  }
```